Conway Proposition on Phragmen Lindelof
Phragmen Lindelof Corollary
Above is a corollary proven in Conway from the Phragmen Lindelof Theorem. Following is another corollary, which uses the previous corollary on which I am stuck. Corollary 2. I am having trouble seeing how $F(z) = f(z) e^{-\epsilon z^a}$ is an appropriate function to use, given that we are trying to reduce it to $|F(z)| < P e^{|z|^b}$ with $b < a$. From the assumptions, $|F(z)| = |f(z) e^{-\epsilon z^a}| \le P e^{\delta |z|^a - \epsilon \Re z^a}$, which runs into the issue that $\Re z^a$ may be arbitrarily small. From there, I am unsure how to prove the bound with a lesser power of $|z|$.

you do not read carefully - the inequality needed is only for $x>0$ where $Rx^a=x^a$

@Conrad I am not sure what you mean, given that the inequality must be proven for all z in G sufficiently large.

Just read the proof linked - $G$ is split into two parts (above and below real axis) and the proof done separately; on each of the subdomains the hypothesis bounds $f$ on the non real part of the boundary so only a bound on the positive real axis is required to apply previous theorem

Thank you, I did not observe the proof being split.
